# Make sort order in citation call-outs independent of value of maxcitenames counter

Tags: biblatex

My problem is a little tricky. I want my bibliography sorted in a certain way. First it should be sorted by all authors, then by year, then title. This is working fine in most cases, but I have the situation, that I have multiple articles from the same group of researchers and sorting seems to work as follows:
"sort by authors names, but only sort by the first x names, where x is the value of maxcitenames=x (in my case: 3). If the number of authors exceeds the entered value put it at the end of the articles by the first author and sort them there."

So currently the bibliography looks like

> Author, Buthor, Cuthor (2010) bla
>   Author, Buthor, Cuthor (2011) blubb
>   Author, Euthor (2003) bli
>   Author, Buthor, Cuthor, Duthor (2006) blobb

where it should be:

> Author, Buthor, Cuthor (2010) bla
>   Author, Buthor, Cuthor (2011) blubb
>   Author, Buthor, Cuthor, Duthor (2006) blobb
>   Author, Euthor (2003) bli

The ordering in the bibliography is correct, if I increase the value of "maxcitenames". However this increases the number of names after the quote within article (of course). So what I basically need is a syntax, which says that in the text a maximum of 3 names should be mentioned, but the sort order in the bibliography should be alphabetically and should include all the authors. I am using the citet and citep commands provided by natbib.

I hope someone can help me with that issue.

---

Additional information

Syntax:

```
%General
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,
top=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm,
includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%Citation
\usepackage[
style=authoryear-icomp,
mincitenames=1,
maxbibnames=99,
maxcitenames=3,
dashed=false,
url=false,
ibidtracker=false,
sorting=nyt,
natbib=true, 
sortcites=false,
firstinits=false,
uniquelist=false,
backend=bibtex
]{biblatex}


\bibliography{test}
\defbibheading{head}{\section{Texts}}
    \begin{document}
    \section{Intro}
    bla \citep{Author1}
    blub \citep{Author2}
    bli \citep{Author3}
    blobb \citep{Author4}
    \printbibliography[heading=head]
    \end{document}
```

AND the .bib file

```
@book{Author1,
    title = {bla},
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
    date = {2009},
}
@book{Author2,
    title = {bli},
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
    date = {2010},
}

@book{Author3,
    title = {blobb},
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
    date = {2009},
}

@book{Author4,
    title = {blubb},
    author = {Author, A. and Euthor, E.},
    date = {2012},
}
```

Comment: This can possibly have several issues. Please provide a minimal compilable example that demonstrates the problem. It must start with `\documentclass{}`, contain `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and all the code needed in between to replicate the problem. Further it must load all packages needed, but nothing else. In other words: If it is copied into a LaTeX editor it must produce an example document without further modification.

Comment: Sorry. I just added the main part of my document, so you should be able to replicate the problem. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly, using bibtex as a backend causes this problem. If you use exactly your code with biber as a backend, it works as you want.

```
\usepackage[
style=authoryear-icomp,
mincitenames=1,
maxbibnames=99,
maxcitenames=3,
dashed=false,
url=false,
ibidtracker=false,
sorting=nyt,
natbib=true, 
sortcites=false,
firstinits=false,
uniquelist=false,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
```

[image]

Is there any particular reason that you cannot use biber, which would be the best choice for many more other advantages of BibLaTeX anyways.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. It works with biber. The problem was that I was using versions of biber and biblatex, which were not compatible. After the update everything works fine. Tank you for the quick and good support.